# The server certificate on the destination computer

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am working on DevOps In that I am started the working Cross Browser Testing by Following bellow link

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2017/02/14/cross-browser-automate-test/

whenever I am queue the build it will be successes only for the first time but whenever I  restarted my VM(Virtual machine) and connected to it then it gives the below exception.

[image]

Can you please tell me how to resolve the above issue and

Answer (score 0):

> If you create a VM via the portal you do not get a prompt for the DNS.
>   So, VSTS when it deploys for the first time, it installs WINRM and as
>   part of this process installs a SSL Cert based on the address of the
>   server.  So, if by the time you deploy and you've NOT subsequently
>   gone in and input the DNS of your VM in the Public IP resource, it
>   will use the IP address as the CN for the SSL Cert.
>
> This is not an issue if you do not (a) shutdown your VM OR (B) use a
>   static IP but is an issue if you (c) do shutdown your VM OR (d) use a
>   dynamic IP.  (c) & (d) describes our usage.
>
> So, what we did is to automate the creation of the VM and added
>   dnsSettings property to the ARM template template.json and supplied
>   the DNS at runtime time via an inline parameter value:
>
> ```
> {
>             "name": "[parameters('publicIpAddressName')]",
>             "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIpAddresses",
>             "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
>             "location": "[parameters('location')]",
>             "properties": {
>                 "publicIpAllocationMethod": "[parameters('publicIpAddressType')]",
>                 "dnsSettings" : {
>                     "domainNameLabel" : "[parameters('virtualMachineName')]"
>                 }
>             }
>         },
> ```

More information, you can refer to this thread: [The SSL certificate contains a common name (CN) that does not match the hostname](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4dcc3a95-5191-4619-84f2-b1589744657d/the-ssl-certificate-contains-a-common-name-cn-that-does-not-match-the-hostname?forum=TFService)